# Facebook connect can my website be in "Sandbox mode" and still work in production?

Tags: facebook

Facebook Connect is working for my website in development and I am able to login but I am wondering if that is just because I am listed as a developer for the application? Must I submit the website for review before I deploy to production or can I deploy it and people will be able to login?

Thanks!

Comment: There's no need to ` submit the website for review `, you've created the app with your developers account now you can do anything you want to. Just disable the `sandbox` mode before making it live.

Answer (score 0):

Being listed as a developer allows you to test the app in Sandbox mode. Other users can't see or use anything of your app when it's in Sandbox mode. Disabling Sandbox mode makes it "live" for all users, so no review is required. However, when you use the Open Graph Protocol, you must submit your stories for review before users will be able to use them.